# ¿Por qué necesito lanzar un RunTimeException?

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


public ArrayList<Coffee> getAllCoffees()
{
    try
    {
        conn = ConnectionPool.getPool().getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM coffees";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        ArrayList<Coffee> coffeeList = new ArrayList<Coffee>();
        Coffee coffee = null;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            coffee = new Coffee();
            coffee.setCof_name(rs.getString("cof_name"));
            coffee.setSup_id(rs.getInt("sup_id"));
            coffee.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            coffee.setSales(rs.getDouble("sales"));
            coffee.setTotal(rs.getDouble("total"));
            coffeeList.add(coffee);
        }
        return coffeeList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(rs != null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
            if(stmt != null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if(conn != null)
            {
                ConnectionPool.getPool().releaseConnection(conn);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando retiro la línea `throw new RuntimeException(ex)` me dice: el método debe retornar un resultado de tipo `ArrayList<Coffee>`. Aunque el objeto `coffeeList` es de tipo `ArrayList`. Pero cuando incluyo la línea `throw new RuntimeException(ex)` el mensaje de error se va. ¿Puede alguien explicarme cual es la razón del `RuntimeException`?

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estas forzando a terminar tu método `public ArrayList<Coffee> getAllCoffees()` mediante `throw new RuntimeException(ex);`, para que se ejecute correctamente el método, este debe retornar un tipo  `ArrayList<Coffee>`.

Como solución retorna un `ArrayList` vació del tipo requerido, en lugar de llamar `throw` :

```
  catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //throw new RuntimeException();

        return new ArrayList<Coffee>() ;

    }
```

---

Considero esto una mejor practica en lugar de solo retornar un valor null, `return null` ya que al llamar el método se espera recibir un `ArrayList` de objetos `Coffee`.

Answer (score 1):

La *RuntimeException* se usa para en el caso de error terminar el programa en forma controlado. Con la *RuntimeException*, el compilador no se queja porque existen solamente dos posibilidades:

El código funciona correctamente sin tirar excepciones y devuelve un objeto de tipo *ArrayList* como declarado en el método, **o** el programa termina en uno de los bloques *catch* con una *RuntimeException*.

Sin tirar la excepción en esta parte existía la posibilidad que el programa sigue corriendo pero sin devolver un resultado.

Como alternativa a los *RuntimeException*, podrías agregar

```
return null:
```

al fin del bloque *final*.

Comment: O mejor aún: tener código más limpio de nulos y declarar la lista a retornar al inicio e inicializarla como `new ArrayList<>()`, llenar sus elementos dentro de la lectura del `ResultSet` y luego del bloque `finally` devolver esta lista.

Comment: Devolver _null_ o un resultado vacío en el fondo es una decisión de arquitectura, se ve en ambas formas. Depende un poco del gusto que uno prefiere, devolver _null_ arriesga _NullPointerException_ en otra parte del código, pero evita ofusca errores que resultan en devolver resultados vacíos.

Comment: [Puntero Nulo: El error de los mil millones de dólares](https://www.fayerwayer.com/2009/03/puntero-nulo-el-error-de-los-mil-millones-de-dolares/). Ah, por cierto, en programación funcional (la "nueva" tendencia), es mejor tener y manejar objetos vacíos antes que `null`. Y nunca se sabe cuando el sistema no está hecho a prueba de NPEs (sobretodo en sistemas legados). En resumen, es mejor evitar nulos. Prefiero una funcionalidad que no muestra los datos a que lance un NPE donde no debía.

Comment: Con ganas me podría perder en un debate sobre eso :D pero cuento corto, creo que es altamente dependiente del contexto de un sistema si es preferible de tener datos erróneos o una falla visible por excepción. :)

Comment: Estoy armado para el debate. Puedes crear la sala de chat cuando gustes :)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51913/npe-o-resultado-vacio

Answer (score 1):

Bueno aunque el hilo es un poco viejo, la mejor opción para mi sin duda es devolver un `ArrayList` vacío pero no haciendo un `new ArrayList<>()` sino usando la clase `Collections`.

La 'firma' o signature en inglés del método que estás usando te obliga a devolver un objeto de tipo `Arraylist<Coffe>` por lo que si no lo haces te marca el error ya que el método no cumple con la firma.

Otra forma de cumplir ese 'contrato' es lanzar una excepción, que en este caso al tratarse de una excepción `RuntimeException` no necesita ser especificada en la firma.

Por otro lado dejo aquí una pequeña refactorización del código

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

/**
 * Mejor devolver list que ArrayList
 * List es una interfaz y de esta forma podrías devolver
 * por ejemplo una LinkedList
*/
public List<Coffee> getAllCoffees(){
    try{
        conn = ConnectionPool.getPool().getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM coffees";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        List<Coffee> coffeeList = new ArrayList<Coffee>();
        Coffee coffee = null;
        while(rs.next()) {
            coffee = new Coffee();
            coffee.setCof_name(rs.getString("cof_name"));
            coffee.setSup_id(rs.getInt("sup_id"));
            coffee.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            coffee.setSales(rs.getDouble("sales"));
            coffee.setTotal(rs.getDouble("total"));
            coffeeList.add(coffee);
        }
        return coffeeList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }finally{
       close(rs, stmt, conn);
    }
}

private void close(Autocloseable... autocloseable){
    if (autocloseable != null){
        for (final Autocloseable clos : autocloseable){
            if (clos != null){
                try{
                    clos.close();
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aunque no se que clases estás utilizando lo más seguro es que implementen la interfaz Autocloseable, por lo que tiene sentido crear el método close y de esta forma queda el código más legible siempre que conn.close() sea analogo a  `ConnectionPool.getPool().releaseConnection(conn);` que deberia ser así aunque esto último son sólo especulaciones.

Por otro lado cabe decir que sería mejor tener un Logger y no hacer uso de `e.printStackTrace();`